# Token-pasting operator (##) is eating spaces in my C++ macro

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I was having trouble with the following macro, and I found out that the token-pasting operator (`##`) is eating the space between `static` and the return type:

```
#define MY_FUNCTION(aReturnType) static ##aReturnType MyFunction() { }
```

So the preprocessor was turning this:

```
MY_FUNCTION(bool)
```

into this:

```
staticbool MyFunction() { }
```

which caused weird compilation errors.

I came up with the idea of putting parentheses around the `static` keyword:

```
// This works but is kind of weird
#define MY_FUNCTION(aReturnType) (static) ##aReturnType MyFunction() { }
```

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: whitespace-eating is part of the job description of this operator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you don't want to use token pasting here.  If you change the macro to

```
#define MY_FUNCTION(aReturnType) static aReturnType MyFunction() { }
```

Then if you write

```
MY_FUNCTION(bool)
```

it will expand out into

```
static bool MyFunction() { }
```

I am assuming that this is what you want to do, since I can't see what you're trying to paste the `aReturnType` argument to the macro onto.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am a little rusty on C++ macros and forgot that I could just use the macro parameter as-is.

Answer (score 3):

As it should do? You told it to paste together `static` and `bool`. If you don't want that and you want `static bool` instead, then *don't paste them together*?